# I can't place two images on the center of layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I try to place the two images in the center of layout,
but I have the extra space on the top and on the bottom of my layout.
Images are png files.

[image]

Important part of my XML is below:

```
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:background="@color/backDark2"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageDriverProfileFace"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/driver"
                        />
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageDriverProfileCar"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/car"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas please how to remove mentioned extra space?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` param to your imageview's